# Is there anyway to tell if a transaction was submitted by a light client on a substrate blockchain?

Tags: transactions, nodes, data-analytics, light-client

Interested in calculating the number of transactions submitted by type of node. Ie seeing how many transactions are originating from light clients vs full-nodes.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to identify the source of a transaction. In general we are trying to make transaction submission as anynomous as possible. Including anything to identify the node type or similar would defeat this goal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Smoldot; a submitted transaction is validated and then send to full nodes.

The full nodes will handle this transaction like any other transaction coming from another peer; validating it, and if correct, adding it to their transaction pool.

Eventually the transaction will be added to a block. Smoldot is checking this for a certain amount of time and also if it is finalized. It updates the Smoldot user about this.

However, generally there is no way of identifying whether a transaction is submitted through a light client or a full node.